# Need to detect when app is unable to connect to server when uploading JSON document in iOS

Tags: ios, json, plist, nsurlconnection

I am uploading a JSON document from my app to a server on the web, and I am able to do this successfully.  However, what I need to do now is detect when there is no WiFi or 3G connectivity and prompt the user with an alert that informs the user that the app is unable to connect, and then give them the option to save the JSON document as a .plist file locally.

Here is the code that I have thus far:

This is my method that uploads my JSON document to the server:

```
- (void) sendJsonDoc:(NSString *)jDoc {

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myWebsite.php"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jDoc length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];

    [request setHTTPBody:[jDoc dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

}




- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    int code = [httpResponse statusCode];
    NSLog(@"%d", code);

}
```

Here is the code that I have in order to save the JSON document locally as a plist file:

```
NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"jsonDoc.plist"];

    // If the file doesn't exist in the Documents Folder, copy it.
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        NSString *sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jsonDoc" ofType:@"plist"];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:path error:nil];
    }

    // Load the Property List.
    NSString *loadJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

How do I detect in my sendJsonDoc method when there is no connection and issue an alert to the user that prompts them that there is no connection, and if they want to save the document locally?

Comment: In addition to checking the reachability - as proposed by PaReeOhNos - you'll also need to handle all errors from the NSURLConnection because the network connectivity could be lost in the middle of a transmission.

Comment: Do you have a link to a page that shows how to handle these errors?  How many error's are there to handle besides 404?

Comment: You need to implement `connection:didReceiveResponse:` and check the status code (`NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response; if (httpResponse.statusCode != 200) ...`). And you'll need to implement `connection:didFailWithError:`. That's all I can think of.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this issue for me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Reachability framework/library.

tonymillion made a nice version of the Apple supplied one that has been adapted to use ARC and adds support for blocks as well. The readme on github also explains how you can subscribe to notifications for the change of connection :)

[Check out the project here](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)

Comment: No worries :) As Codo mentioned though, just be sure to handle any exceptions that happen mid connection :)